# Postgresql: Return most recent record based on where conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to return a set of rows where if a `car_id` in the table below contains a duplicate, just use the most recent entry by `created_on` and apply the `WHERE` clause to the most recent entry. In which case if the most recent entry doesn't satisfy, do not return anything.

SQLFiddle: For the question - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/cc0a5/2

**Note**: Please see edit - statement at the end of question for further clarification

**Data**

**Table**: `car_wash`

Here is a sample table with all the data.

| id | car_id | next_clean | end_at | created_on |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 79d | d48 | 2022-06-25 18:29:32.210955 +00:00 | NULL | 2022-06-25 18:34:32.235425 +00:00 |
| 1f3 | 645 | 2022-06-25 18:29:32.210955 +00:00 | NULL | 2022-06-25 18:34:32.235434 +00:00 |
| 397 | d41 | 2022-06-25 18:29:32.210955 +00:00 | NULL | 2022-06-25 18:34:32.235435 +00:00 |
| 435 | 372 | 2022-06-25 18:29:32.210955 +00:00 | NULL | 2022-06-25 18:34:32.235436 +00:00 |
| 3d5 | d41 | 2022-06-25 18:32:52.068891 +00:00 | 2022-06-25 18:34:32.269289 +00:00 | 2022-06-25 18:34:32.269252 +00:00 |
| 2df | 372 | 2022-07-25 18:35:32.068891 +00:00 | 2022-06-25 18:35:32.269293 +00:00 | 2022-06-25 18:35:32.269291 +00:00 |

Based on the data, I want to retrieve rows of cars that need to be cleaned i.e their `next_clean` date has elapsed, ~and the log of their previous recorded clean (`end_at`) is NULL, i.e the clean never took place or finished.~

In the event a car appears multiple times e.g. `car_id: 372` for `id: 435` and `id: 2df`, then only take into consideration the most recent (`created_on`) record i.e `id: 2df` and if `id: 2df` meets the criteria mentioned above return it, if not do not return it or even `id: 372`. I only care about the most recent entry.

For the attempted postgres query below, assume that `now()` takes place between the `next_clean` dates for `id: 435` and `id: 2df` (a month in the future), meaning `2df` is in the future and will fail the `WHERE` check. *For those wondering why `id: 2df` has a populated `end_at` field even though the `next_clean` hasn't taken place. I'm using the `end_at` to signify a clean happened, and the `next_clean` stores when a new clean should take place)*

**What I Have Tried**

Based on numerous solutions, the use of window functions was suggested, but I am not sure I'm applying it correctly

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT
             id,
             car_id,
             next_clean,
             end_at,
             created_on,
             row_number() over (partition by car_id order by created_on desc) as rn
      FROM car_wash
      WHERE car_wash.user_id = 'some-id'
        AND (car_wash.next_clean <= now())
        AND car_wash.end_at IS NULL
      LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

**Result**

| id | car_id | next_clean | end_at | created_on | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 435 | 372 | 2022-06-25 18:29:32.210955 +00:00 | NULL | 2022-06-25 18:34:32.235436 +00:00 | 1 |
| 1f3 | 645 | 2022-06-25 18:29:32.210955 +00:00 | NULL | 2022-06-25 18:34:32.235434 +00:00 | 1 |
| 397 | d41 | 2022-06-25 18:29:32.210955 +00:00 | NULL | 2022-06-25 18:34:32.235435 +00:00 | 1 |
| 79d | d48 | 2022-06-25 18:29:32.210955 +00:00 | NULL | 2022-06-25 18:34:32.235425 +00:00 | 1 |

The problem with this result is that since `id: 2df` fails the check as it's `next_clean` is in the future, `id: 435` for `car_id: 372` is returned which is **not** what I want (as it unfortunately does pass the check, but I only want to focus on the most recently created `car_id`).

**Intended/Expected**

| id | car_id | next_clean | end_at | created_on | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1f3 | 645 | 2022-06-25 18:29:32.210955 +00:00 | NULL | 2022-06-25 18:34:32.235434 +00:00 | 1 |
| 397 | d41 | 2022-06-25 18:29:32.210955 +00:00 | NULL | 2022-06-25 18:34:32.235435 +00:00 | 1 |
| 79d | d48 | 2022-06-25 18:29:32.210955 +00:00 | NULL | 2022-06-25 18:34:32.235425 +00:00 | 1 |

**Edit**: @jholkin raised a good point regarding why we return `id: 3d5` in the first place since `end_at` is not null. It introduces conflicting priorities. So ideally the `WHERE` clause should only care that the `created_on` is most recent if there are duplicates, and that the `next_clean` is `<= now()`. The expected result is still the same as now `end_at` isn't a factor.

Comment: hm, 372 has the latest created date so you want the top 3 sorted by date asc?

Comment: So first number the rows. Then apply the filter with `rn = 1` and the other conditions. Essentially move the extra checks to the outer query.

Comment: I have added a SQLFiddle to the question for easier interaction

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/cc0a5/2

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DISTINCT ON` to produce only the first row per group (per `car_id`) according to an ordering (`created_on DESC`). Then, filtering is trivial.

For example:

```
select *
from (
  select distinct on (car_id) *
  from car_wash
  order by car_id, created_on desc
) x
where next_clean <= now() and end_at is null
```

Answer (score 1):

if the condition says, that when there are more than two records of the same car_id, it should take the most recent one based on the create_on field and this record must have null value in its end_at field, why should it return the record with id 397? If the most current create_on value is id 3d5.
this query should help you:

```
select t.* 
from ( select distinct on (cw.car_id) cw.id, cw.car_id ,
last_value (cw.next_clean) over (partition by cw.next_clean order by cw.next_clean desc) as next_clean ,
cw.end_at ,
(cw.created_on) as created_on  from car_wash cw ) t 
where t.next_clean <= now()     and t.end_at is null;
```

Comment: You raise a good point ... The `end_at` `WHERE` check introduced a conflict with how I was populating data and what I was trying to do. So omitting it actually provided the intended result

Answer (score -1):

you can do it with FIRST_VALUE()  window functions:

https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/postgresql-first_value-function/

[https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html#:~:text=A%20window%20function%20performs%20a,done%20with%20an%20aggregate%20function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html#:%7E:text=A%20window%20function%20performs%20a,done%20with%20an%20aggregate%20function).
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html